# SQLCommand Agrega comillas extras en parametros

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Tengo el siguiente código en C# para llamar a un *stored procedure* en una base de datos SQL. Todo funciona bien, pero en el parámetro que le paso me agrega 2 comillas extras.

```
    {
        try
        {
            

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(labId)))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "sigma_user.Usuarios_ValidarUsuario";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Usuario", userLogin);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "?????''?W??9Fj?b";
               // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", userPassword);

                var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var result = returnParameter.Value;
                conn.Close();
                return (int)result;
            }
        }
```

Cuando ejecuta el *stored procedure* lo hace la siguiente manera:

```sql
exec sigma_user.Usuarios_ValidarUsuario @Usuario=N'prueba',@Password='?????''''?W??9Fj?b'
```

Como verán, agrega 2 comillas.

Comment: No está agregando comillas extras. En SQL una comilla simple (`'`), dentro de una cadena (que está delimitada por comillas simples), se representa con una doble comilla `''`, por ejemplo, la cadena `John's`, se representa como `'John''s'`.

Comment: Entiendo, pero entonces como podría solucionar el problema entonces?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? pregunto, porque has descrito una situación, pero no has mencionado que esto represente algún tipo de problema, o cuál es ese?

Comment: El problema es que el valor en la base de datos, tiene 2 comillas, y cuando lo ejecutar el store manda el parametro con 4 comillas. Por esto al comparar las contraseñas no son iguales.

Comment: El que muestras en el ejemplo tiene solo dos comillas. O estás mostrando mal el ejemplo, o estás apuntando hacia el lado equivocado.

Comment: Exacto en el parametro del SQLCommand tiene solo 2 comillas. Luego si te fijas mas abajo esta la ejecución del store que genera el SQLCommand con ExecuteNonQuery y ahi si te fijas tiene 4 comillas. Esa ejecución la saque del SQLProfiler, lo que yo necesito es que la ejecución del store por parte del SQLCommand se haga con 2 comillas como las que puse en el parametro. Se entiende la situacion ahora?

Comment: Enzo, es lo que te explico. Que en SQL, las 4 comillas _visibles_, representan solamente 2 comillas dentro de la cadena, ya que cada comilla simple, dentro de una cadena, se representa con una comilla doble. Lee de nuevo mi primer comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer esta trampa:

```
"?????''?W??9Fj?b".replace("'" , "' || chr(39) || '")
```

valores vistos desde c#

```
"?????''?W??9Fj?b" -> "?????' || chr(39) || '?W??9Fj?b"
```

el rdbs lo evalúa como:

```
expr -> '?????' || chr(39) || '?W??9Fj?b' 
expr -> ?????''?W??9Fj?b
```

de esta forma el parámetro lo interpreta el compilador del motor de bases de datos (por ejemplo postgres,oracle) pero no se qué operador de concatenación usar pues la db no es especificada.

No es ortodoxo pero ante medidas desesperadas ayuda a prevenir que se dañe el sql haciendo una cerradura de los strings :

```
 ' || chr(39) || '
 * Cerradura inicial del string
       
 
                 * apertura dle nuevo string.
```

Comment: La base de datos es SQL Server, como seria la expresión en ese caso?